# C++ makefile error

Tags: c++, makefile

When I build a project usng Eclipse I get the following error regarding the Makefile:µ

```
Type make: *** No rule to make target `hello.exe', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

My Makefile is this:

```
all: hello

hello: main.o factorial.o hello.o
   g++ main.o factorial.o hello.o -o hello

main.o: main.cpp
   g++ -c main.cpp

factorial.o: factorial.cpp
   g++ -c factorial.cpp

hello.o: hello.cpp
   g++ -c hello.cpp

clean:
   rm -rf *o hello
```

Does anyone know which is my mistake? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know if this is a Unix/Windows difference, but your rule is for making `hello`, not `hello.exe`; is that what you mean?

Comment: I don't know. There is an error and I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

1st, good luck developing with Eclipse, you need a lot of Zen for that

2nd, a quick recap about how to read a makefile:

```
target: requiredTarget(optional)
 how to generate the target
```

so, as you can see, reading the first line of your makefile is like saying: " I have a target named *all* and this target requires the target *hello* in order to be generated ".

Now the target `all` is a special one, it's the one that is implicit, so when you or your IDE just type `make` in your shell `make all` is implied ( of course you can specify your target with `make`, the special case is just applied when no building target is specified via the command line ).

The chain begins with `make` or an explicit `make all` that always leads to build the `all` target, the `all` target calls in the `hello` target but since you are on Windows, the suffix `.exe` is automatically added and your `make` can't find a target named `hello.exe`.

Basically you need to manage your OS specific building steps and you have to edit that makefile to let this work, or you can wait for someone that is more into Eclipse to see if there is a good makefile-related option to manage this platform-specific stuff.

a good introduction is http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/makefiles.html

consider QTcreator for C++ developing.

Comment: To avoid any confusion, the default is whichever target appears first, not the one called `all`.

Comment: Or, the dependency of the `.DEFAULT` pseudo-target. E.g. `.DEFAULT: all`.

Comment: BTW: I really doubt that `make` is adding `.exe` to the dependency name automatically. That just wouldn't make sense, since `make` just doesn't have any clue about the target *type*. My suspicion is that Eclipse calls `make hello.exe` instead, leading to bespoke error message.

Comment: @MichaelWild i see your point but i would also like to remind that almost all the GNU software available under Windows is a porting from linux and you can't assume that similar software will have the same behaviour on different platforms. This is my experience and often it's just like that with both make and mingw/g++ .

Comment: True, but there's no way for `make` to know that `hello` builds an executable. Of course, it could inspect the rule, but then that would be very fragile indeed. I just tried it, and it works just fine. It must be the Eclipse configuration that invokes the `hello.exe` target.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed the makefile looks for the file 'hello' but this file does not exist because Windows directly creates a 'hello.exe' file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have idea about Eclipse but whatever the `Makefile` you have will work fine in Linux. try to change target name after `all` like this and check out

`all: hello.exe`

`hello.exe: main.o factorial.o hello.o`

`g++ main.o factorial.o hello.o -o hello.exe`